# Azure Logic/Service Bus Queue - How many messages at once with "When a message is received in a queue"?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues

My setup:

- I've created an Azure Service Bus Queue without sessions enabled
- I have an Azure Logic App created with the `When a message is received in a queue (peek-lock)` trigger
- The trigger has an interval of `15 seconds`

My results:

- I'm putting messages on the queue at a faster-than-15-second pace
- My Azure Logic App trigger picks up multiple queue messages at a time, much faster than 1 message every 15 seconds

My questions:

- Is the trigger of this connector designed to pick up more than 1 queued message at a time (during an `Interval`?)?
- If so, how many?
- Is there a way to change the number of messages received at once?
- What, exactly, is the `Interval` setting doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the trigger of this connector designed to pick up more than 1
>   queued message at a time (during an Interval)?

Yes, this trigger can pick up to 50 messages.

You can change the configuration by going to the triggers Settings -> Concurrency control and toggle the button.

[image]
By default, Logic App instances run at the same time, or in parallel. This control changes how new runs are queued and can't be changed after enabling.
To run as many parallel instances as possible, leave this control turned off. To limit the number of parallel runs, turn on this control, and select a limit. To run sequentially, select 1 as the limit.

Comment: If I need to listen to multiple SB queues, would I need to create separate logic app corresponding to each queue?  What is the best practice?  Thanks