# Logic app executed twice for the same message from servicebus queue with message state=Active and Scheduled

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues

A message is being dropped to Service bus queue with ScheduledEnqueueTimeUTC and Service Bus Connector in Logic app has trigger set to pick messages from queue at 12:05AM  EST EveryDay.

Problem: Logic app has picked the same message twice one with Service bus message properties State='Scheduled' and other with state='Active' with same sequenceNumber. May i know when this happens and how can this be solved.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem: Logic app has picked the same message twice one with Service
> bus message properties State='Scheduled' and other with state='Active'
> with same sequenceNumber. May i know when this happens and how can
> this be solved.

Here we discovered one of the workarounds that will meet your needs. To pick and send a message only once, we must set our settings to **split on** as seen below.

[image]

**NOTE: I tried using Logic app standard, as this option is not available in Consumption plan**

[image]

Please refer this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus) & [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60198949/azure-logic-service-bus-queue-how-many-messages-at-once-with-when-a-message-i) for more information .